# How to modify form validators from controller in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am working with Zend Framework 2. I have defined some validation rules within my [Entity class](http://pastebin.com/MzqRB3Hc). These work as expected without any problems.

However, when in 'edit' mode I don't want the two file upload fields to be required. I tried to do `setRequired(false)` for both file upload fields within my [controller action](http://pastebin.com/4NmDrZPW) but it doesn't seem to have any effect on validation, it still throws a 'file was not found' message. What do I need to so the user can submit the form successfully without uploading any files?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

for change form validation in controller, you must remove current validation and set new validation. i hope this help you:

```
$form = new YourForm();
$form->setData ( $yourPostedData () );
$formInputFilter = $form->getInputFilter ();

// change filter
$formInputFilter->remove ( 'your_field' );
$inputFactory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory();
$formInputFilter->add ( $inputFactory->createInput ( array (
    'name' => 'your_field',
    'required' => false
) ) );

if ($form->isValid ()) {
    //...   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [validation groups](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups)

The documentation states:

> Zend\Form provides a proxy method to the underlying InputFilter‘s setValidationGroup() method, allowing us to perform this operation.

And all you need to do is name the fields you require validating (omit the upload element names)

```
$form->setValidationGroup(array('foo', 'bar'));
if ($form->isValid()) {
   // $data contains just 'foo' and 'bar'
   $data = $form->getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message I was getting 'file was not found' made me realise the issue I was having was deeper than setting the validators/filters.

The form is processed via an AJAX script using a FormData object. I added the files to the object using:

`oAgencyFormData.append("cssFilename", document.getElementById('logoName').files[0]);`

and the object is then passed to the AJAX call. I realised that in the case when a file is not uploaded 'undefined' is being passed to the script. So I separated it into a variable which is assigned "" if no file has been specified:

```
    var oLogoFile   =   document.getElementById('logoName').files[0];   
    var oCssFile    =   document.getElementById('cssFilename').files[0];

    // define defaults for file upload fields (used if nothing is uploaded)
    if(typeof oLogoFile === 'undefined'){
        oLogoFile = '';
    };

    if(typeof oCssFile === 'undefined'){
        oCssFile = '';
    };
```

Once I did this then file validators worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

```
$form->remove('your_field');
$center->getInputFilter()->remove('your_field');
```

Hope it helps!